# IronPython XML-Reader in .Net 2.0

Tags: python, xml, ironpython

I created a XML-Reader that creates a pretty stupid formated List, the script thats goint to use it needs it this way though.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

PATH_IN = "<Path>\sweep.xml"

tree = ET.parse(PATH_IN)
root = tree.getroot()

Input = []
for project in root:

    for design in project:
        list_lvl2 = []
        list_lvl2.append(project.get('name'))
        list_lvl2.append(design.get('name'))
        list_lvl2.append('')

        list_lvl3 = [] 
        for param in design:
            list_lvl4 = []
            list_lvl4.append(param.get('name'))
            list_lvl5 = []
            for steps in param:
                list_lvl5.append(steps.text)
            list_lvl4.append(list_lvl5)
            list_lvl4.append(param.get('unit'))
            list_lvl3.append(list_lvl4)
        list_lvl2.append(list_lvl3)
        Input.append(list_lvl2)
```

Problem is I have to execute it in the Scripting Interface of a Program which uses IronPython 2.6.10920.0 on .NET 2.0.50727.5466. And it throws following error:

```
*Global - Messages
  [error] ImportException: No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead  In file "<Path>/sweep.py", line 36 ---- While executing script: <Path>/sweep.py
  [error] Error executing script in <Path>\sweep.py:
  [error] ImportException: No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead  In file "<Path>/sweep.py", line 36 ---- While executing script: <Path>/sweep.py
  [error] Error executing script in <Path>\sweep.py:
```

What I don't understand is that this script which uses the same module works fine:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

path = "<Path>\projects.xml"

root = ET.Element('xml')
projects = oDesktop.GetProjectList()
for i in projects:
    project = ET.SubElement(root,'project')
    project.set('name', i)
    designs = oDesktop.SetActiveProject(i).GetTopDesignList()
    for u in designs:
        design = ET.SubElement(project,'design')
        design.set('name', u)
        vars = oDesktop.SetActiveProject(i).GetDesign(u).GetVariables()
        for z in vars:
            param = ET.SubElement(design,'param')
            param.set('name', z)
            value = ET.SubElement(param,'value')
            value.text = oDesktop.SetActiveProject(i).GetDesign(u).GetVariableValue(z)
f = open(path, "w")
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(f)

f.close()
```

oDesktop and such are just programspecific functions that fetch data.
I really don't understand why the first script won't work, I'm guessing because of NET 2.0.

UPDATE: After looking up what expat is, I'm even more confused since I never use it anywhere and all elementtree functions I use should be supported whith this version of Iron Python. Still it gives me the expat error on this line `tree = ET.parse(PATH_IN)`

UPDATE: I tried using `from elementtree import SimpleXMLTreeBuilder as ET` which resulted in:

```
*Global - Messages
  [error] ImportException: No module named elementtree  In file "<Path>/sweep.py", line 3 ---- While executing script: <Path>/sweep.py
  [error] Error executing script in <Path>\sweep.py:
```

Comment: By default `expat` is used by `ElementTree` to parse the xml. Your other script is *writing* xml not *parsing* it, so there's no problem. It's still strange that you get this error, though. Maybe your IronPython install is broken? Try using [another treebuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2067177/1002469), or even finding/making your own treebuilder using  a .NET XML parser.

Comment: I don't have a elementtree folder in my iron python dictionary are there any other xml reader that don't use expat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue here is that ElementTree uses expat for xml parsing, but expat (a C library made available to Python via a CPython wrapper) cannot be used from IronPython.

However, ElementTree can use a different tree builder driven by a different parser, e.g. the XMLReader parser in .NET. A search for "xmlreader treebuilder" yields [this result](http://pydoc.net/Python/Aglyph/1.1.0/aglyph.compat.ipyetree/) which seems to both describe your problem *and* provide an alternative treebuilder implementation (MIT license) which uses XMLReader.

Comment: I already found this https://github.com/ixc/elementtree. It seems that this libary was missing in the IronPython implementation I have to use at work. Whith it i could use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder. Still I wouldn't have figured that out without your help so thank you very much

Comment: oh and expat works in the latest Iron Python version it seems they just had an issue with 2.6 http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/31579