# Error using xml.etree.ElementTree - "use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead"

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Using python 2.7, I have something like

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

file = "./file.xml"
root = ET.parse(file).getroot()
```

This runs on my normal machine fine, running Ubuntu 14.04. However when running on a different machine, in an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual box on Windows, I get the error

"No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead"

Other people online have seemed to have similar issues. Some suggested updating and/or reinstalling python. I am using the latest version of python 2 and I've tried a reinstall. Nothing I try seems to work. I'm entirely stumped. Is this issue related to the virtual box? This code is part of a project involving others, and as far as I know, this is the first issue with the section of the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SimpleXMLTreeBuilder in elementtree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068510/using-simplexmltreebuilder-in-elementtree)

Comment: I believe the problem there was the python version. I am using the latest version of python 2. I think the problem may be stemming from the virtual machine.