# Using SimpleXMLTreeBuilder

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I am working with `xml.etree.ElementTree`. But I get the following error:

```
No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead
```

I ran into this post [Using SimpleXMLTreeBuilder in elementtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068510/using-simplexmltreebuilder-in-elementtree/2067177#2067177?newreg=17bb54f3e16545139c38fc6cf8585451) @thom_nic, and following its suggestions I do:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from elementtree import SimpleXMLTreeBuilder
ET.XMLTreeBuilder = SimpleXMLTreeBuilder.TreeBuilder
```

But when running `tree = ET.parse(ann_dir)`, the same error appears. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If I type `print(ET.XMLTreeBuilder)` I get `elementtree.SimpleXMLTreeBuilder.TreeBuilder`

Comment: What version of Python do you use? Where does `elementree`in from `elementtree import SimpleXMLTreeBuilder` come from? Please show us the complete code that produces the error (provide a [mcve]).

Comment: I have **python 2.7.13** version.
I am trying to run the following code:
`import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

`test = '/media/juliocesar//annotations/raccoon-1.xml'`

`tree = ET.parse(test)`

But the following error appears:

Comment: `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 651, in parse
    parser = XMLParser(target=TreeBuilder())
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1476, in __init__
    "No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead"`

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding code and tracebacks in comments.

Comment: `elementree` comes from http://effbot.org/media/downloads/elementtree-1.2.6-20050316.tar.gz

Comment: That is an old verson of ElementTree. I can't see any reason to use it. ElementTree is part of the Python standard library since Python 2.5.

Comment: do you refer to `import xml.etree.ElementTree`?

Comment: Do not use the ElementTree version that you downloaded from effbot.org. You should be using `xml.etree.ElementTree`, which comes with Python 2.7.