# Python 2.7 - No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead - source code install

Tags: python, openpyxl, elementtree

I'm working on a server that doesn't allow Python installs (pip, easy_install), so I have to place the source code into a local directory to get Python + openpyxl running.

I have Python2.7 and openpyxl-2.5.8 available, as well as openpyxl dependencies.  However, when openpyxl calls builtins.py, I get the

```
ImportError: No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead
```

expat.py is available in python2.7/Lib/xml/parsers, but I assume due to the the way Python was 'installed' it can't recognize something, possibly related to C extensions (based on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/tzmakclSXJc).

Per @thom_nic's advice at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067177, I got the old source code for elementtree and tried pointing XMLTreeBuilder in ElementTree to the SimpleXMLTreeBuilder as:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from elementtree import SimpleXMLTreeBuilder 
ElementTree.XMLTreeBuilder = SimpleXMLTreeBuilder.TreeBuilder
```

However, I still get the same error.  Full traceback below for reference.  Any ideas on how to get around this, since I can't reinstall Python or run `yum update` or anything like that?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python_packages/python2.7/Lib/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/home/python_packages/python2.7/Lib/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/release/create_sheet.py", line 18, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "/home/python_packages/openpyxl-2.5.8/openpyxl/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "/home/python_packages/openpyxl-2.5.8/openpyxl/workbook/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .workbook import Workbook
  File "/home/python_packages/openpyxl-2.5.8/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 7, in <module>
    from openpyxl.worksheet import Worksheet
  File "/home/python_packages/openpyxl-2.5.8/openpyxl/worksheet/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .worksheet import Worksheet
  File "/home/python_packages/openpyxl-2.5.8/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 35, in <module>
    from openpyxl.cell import Cell
  File "/home/python_packages/openpyxl-2.5.8/openpyxl/cell/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cell import Cell, WriteOnlyCell
  File "/home/python_packages/openpyxl-2.5.8/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 46, in <module>
    from openpyxl.styles.styleable import StyleableObject
  File "/home/python_packages/openpyxl-2.5.8/openpyxl/styles/styleable.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .builtins import styles
  File "/home/python_packages/openpyxl-2.5.8/openpyxl/styles/builtins.py", line 1350, in <module>
    ('Normal', NamedStyle.from_tree(fromstring(normal))),
  File "/home/python_packages/python2.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1310, in XML
    parser = XMLParser(target=TreeBuilder())
  File "/home/python_packages/python2.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1482, in __init__
    "No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead"
ImportError: No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead
```

Comment: is virtualenv installed? maybe you can set a virtualenv and install any lib you want

Comment: I just asked if I can set it up via virtualenv, and apparently it is "problematic" so I don't think I want to push it.  Technically, there is no way to install any Python module because none are on the approved list of installations, so I think I'm already operating under a questionable workaround since we need openpyxl working...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a seriously borked install of Python 2.7. The SimpleXMLBuilder tip almost certainly isn't relevant. If you can install lxml locally using pip then you could monkey patch that in but I suspect you'll have even more problems with its dependencies. But basically a clean and updated Python 2.7 is what you need.

Comment: I was reading other threads and bug reports on this, and a lot of times I saw mention of expat.py using C extensions and how some libraries can't support that, so I think you're right, the python install isn't doing something right.  For now, I just commented out the openpyxl built-in styles, since that's the only instance when it needs to call ElementTree in general.

Comment: openpyxl will use a pure Python version of ElementTree if cElementTree so you should be seeing that problemt at all.