# Unable to parse valid xml in cpython 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, xml, cpython

I'm trying to parse xml file in Python script, which is working inside the C++ application. When I'm trying to run this script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('somexml.xml' ).getroot()
```

I always receive an error:

```
RunScriptFail: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1500, in __init__
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "xml\parsers\expat.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyexpat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1503, in __init__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyexpat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1202, in parse
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 589, in parse
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1505, in __init__
ImportError: No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead

Error parsing script
```

But pyexpat.pyd exists in lib folder of cpython. How can I fix it? Or may be I can use some workaround for it?
Solution from [Using SimpleXMLTreeBuilder in elementtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068510/using-simplexmltreebuilder-in-elementtreenot) works for me

Answer (score 0):

I found that needed pyexpat.pyd is not copied into distribution. I added it ad that resolved my issue